# Not found: FeedInputs: unable to find feed output TensorFlow

Tags: c++, model, tensorflow

I was trying this example of using Tensorflow saved model in c++ in this website: 
https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f#.ji310n4zo

It works well. But it does not save the values of the variables ***a*** and ***b*** as it only saves the graph not the variables. I tried to replace the following line:

```
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, 'models/', 'graph.pb', as_text=False)
```

with

```
saver.save(sess, 'models/graph', global_step=0)
```

of course after creating the saver object. It does not work and it outputs:

***Not found: FeedInputs: unable to find feed output a***

I checked the nodes the Nodes that are loaded and they are only:

> _SOURCE
>
> _SINK

while in the write_graph function and then load the model in C++, I got the following nodes loaded:

> _SOURCE
>
> _SINK
>
> save/restore_slice_1/shape_and_slice
>
> save/restore_slice_1/tensor_name
>
> save/restore_slice/shape_and_slice
>
> save/restore_slice/tensor_name
>
> save/save/shapes_and_slices
>
> save/save/tensor_names
>
> save/Const
>
> save/restore_slice_1
>
> save/restore_slice
>
> b
>
> save/Assign_1
>
> b/read
>
> b/initial_value
>
> b/Assign
>
> a
>
> save/Assign
>
> save/restore_all
>
> save/save
>
> save/control_dependency
>
> a/read
>
> c
>
> a/initial_value
>
> a/Assign
>
> init
>
> Tensor

and even the graph file that is created by saver.save() is much smaller, 165B, compared to the one created by write_graph, 1.9KB.

Comment: I think I know now the reason. It is because write_graph writes the graph without the values for the variables while saver.save writes the values for the variables without the graph :). Not sure why they did it that way! I could not find a way to read the graph and then load the values in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is the best way of solving the problem but at least it solves it.

As write_graph can also store the values of the constants, I added the following code to the python just before writing the graph with write_graph function:

```
for v in tf.trainable_variables():
    vc = tf.constant(v.eval())
    tf.assign(v, vc, name="assign_variables")
```

This creates constants that store variables' values after being trained and then create tensors "***assign_variables***" to assign them to the variables. Now, when you call write_graph, it will store the variables' values in the file.

The only remaining part is to call these tensors "***assign_variables***" in the c code to make sure that your variables are assigned with the constants values that are stored in the file. Here is a one way to do it:

```
      Status status = NewSession(SessionOptions(), &session);
      std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
      for(int i = 0;status.ok(); i++) {
        char name[100];
        if (i==0)
            sprintf(name, "assign_variables");
        else
            sprintf(name, "assign_variables_%d", i);

        status = session->Run({}, {name}, {}, &outputs);
      }
```

Comment: Answering your own question is appreciated since others can learn from your experience.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way of restoring the variables, by calling the `save/restore_all` operation, that should be present in the graph:

```
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
Tensor checkpoint_filepath(DT_STRING, TensorShape());
checkpoint_filepath.scalar<std::string>()() = "path to the checkpoint file";
status = session->Run( {{ "save/Const", checkpoint_filepath },}, 
                       {}, {"save/restore_all"}, &outputs);
```